# Weird NSDate behaviour, how to normalise for different scenarios?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, foundation

We have different dates maintained throughout the product (dylib, frameworks, applications). So we do have root, console user processes running on the system

There are systems having different behaviors for different calendars selected on them.

System1: Where Gregorian calendar is set (macOS 10.13.6)

```
Date : 2019-07-24 10:02:22 +0000 (Root user process)
Date : 2019-07-24 10:03:31 +0000 (Console user process)
```

System2: Where Budhhist or different calendar is set (macOS 10.13.6)

```
Date : 2019-07-24 10:04:59 +0000 (Root user process)
Date : 2562-07-24 10:05:24 +0000 (Console user process)
```

System3: Where Budhhist or different calendar is set (macOS 10.14)

```
Date : 2562-07-24 10:06:59 +0000 (Root user process)
Date : 2562-07-24 10:07:24 +0000 (Console user process)
```

Here we have set calendar from console user only and date has been print using `NSLog()`.

So how does different systems have different bahaviour, any help, details appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot of discussion about Apple's changes in the Locale handling in 10.14 (see for example [Michael Tsai's blog and associated comments](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/05/07/tying-the-locale-to-the-localization/). It looks like a decision was made in 10.14 to make the date settings be consistent throughout the OS. This was a significant change from the previous versions, and as you point out, has particularly strange effects on console user processes which previously operated a less localized environment.

Unfortunately, there are no signs of this changing in 10.15.  There is a setting that might be useful if your command-line executables are Foundation-based (`CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations`), but that's mostly about localization strings and I haven't experimented with the effects on the time side of things.